# Unable to edit tags for an existing question

Tags: bug, edits

I tried to add the [racket-student-languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/racket-student-languages) tag to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11375701/dr-racket-place-image-not-working), but it won't allow me to do that. When I press the 'Save Edits' button on the edit page, a red error popup appears:

> Title cannot contain "Dr Racket place-image not working".
>   Please provide a title that summarizes your question. For assistance, see: How do I ask a good question?

Yes, the title could be improved, but I only want to add a tag, not edit the title.

Comment: @Flux: I edited the title and the question. Feel free to continue from there.

Comment: The Stackoverflow message should be more clear. It should be more like: " Now you're at it, can you please edit the title as well? The current title doesn't match the standards of asking good questions. For more see 'How do I ask a good question'

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's not a bug, it's a feature. Over time, title validation rules are modified, so sometimes an existing title no longer validates under new rules. You'll have to edit the title as well, if you want to add a tag.

(While you're at it, you should also remove the "thank you" and apply code formatting in the post.)

Comment: Note: this is based on the general expectation that you fix **all** issues with a post when editing it (which is especially true when you don't have full edit privileges and your edit needs to be reviewed).